# Fortran free-format can not read input file

Tags: io, fortran

I have downloaded code from here

http://marineemlab.ucsd.edu/Projects/Occam/2DMT/index.html

When I try examples from Test2,Tesst3,Test6 everything works fine.But with my example,I got

```
 Reading model from MODEL...
          24
           1         202
           1         202
           1         202
           1         202
           1         202
           1         202
           1         202
           1         202
           1         202
           1         202
           1         202
           2         202
  Error reading model file
```

This is the example of the model file that works fine

```
FORMAT:           OCCAM2MTMOD_1.0
MODEL NAME:       TEST MODEL 2
DESCRIPTION:      TEST 2, no frills inversion for conductive prism
MESH FILE:        MESH.TEST2
MESH TYPE:        PW2D
STATICS FILE:     none
PREJUDICE FILE:   none
BINDING OFFSET:   -22000.
NUM LAYERS:       12
2  24
 7 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 7
2  24
 7 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 7
1  24
 7 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 7
1  24
 7 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 7
1  13
 7 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 7
1  13
 7 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 7
1  13
 7 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 7
1  13
 7 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 7
1  13
 7 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 7
1  13
 7 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 7
1  13
 7 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 7
4  13
 7 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 7
NO. EXCEPTIONS:   0
```

I have created MODEL file with more cells

```
BINDING OFFSET:   -5000.
NUM LAYERS:       24
1  202
6 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 6
```

This is the relevant part of the code where problem occurs

```
 write(*,*)nlay

  ! Allocate vars related to the # of layers
  Allocate( irz(nlay)           &
          , nrcol(nlay)         &
          , stat=nAllocErr )
  if (nAllocErr .ne. 0) then
    write(*,*) 'Out of memory.  Try reducing the model size.'
    stop
  endif

  ! Don't know how many cols there are.  So pre-read through the layers
  ! and keep the max #.  Then allocate local vars to hold the data, and
  ! re-read through the layer data.
  do i = 1,nlay
    read (iof,*,end=198,err=199) irz(i), nrcol(i)
    write(*,*)irz(i), nrcol(i)
    read (iof,*,end=198,err=199) (ii, j=1,nrcol(i)) ! discard these for now
  enddo
```

My model file
http://pastebin.com/PJMYz52T

My mesh file
http://pastebin.com/yNcTrmM4

My start.txt
http://pastebin.com/4UKjNkEQ

Why is free-format not capable to properly read my input file?

Comment: Is the model file you posted, exactly the one, you are using? Because it does not match the expectations. There should be 24 layers, you have only one, and that one should have 202 columns, which it doesn't have...

Comment: @haraldkl No ,but I will paste my model file,mesh and start up.

Comment: In your model file you have 102 columns per layer, but you tell the application to expect 202.

Comment: @haraldkl Ok,will change that.